# How to save the exported Excel file in client place?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have exported the data to excel using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll it was working fine but it is downloading in server location only not in client location. How we can download the file in client location. here is the code i have used for exporting to excel And how we can ask the location to save the excel file .

```
DataSet dsColors = objClsCorp.GetBlockColorsForReport();
        if (dsReport.Tables.Count > 0 && dsColors.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            Application ExcelApp = new Application();
            Workbook ExcelWorkBook = null;
            Worksheet ExcelWorkSheet = null;
            ExcelApp.Visible = true;
            ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

            for (int i = 1; i < dsColors.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(); //Adding New sheet in Excel Workbook
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dsColors.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int r = 1; // Initialize Excel Row Start Position  = 1
                ExcelWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets[i + 1];
                //Writing Columns Name in Excel Sheet
                for (int col = 1; col <= dsReport.Tables[0].Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = dsReport.Tables[0].Columns[col - 1].ColumnName;
                }
                r++;

                System.Data.DataTable table = dsReport.Tables[0];
                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Color = '" + dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BlockColor"].ToString()+"'";
                    table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();

                    //Writing Rows into Excel Sheet
                    for (int row = 0; row < table.Rows.Count; row++) //r stands for ExcelRow and col for ExcelColumn
                    {
                        // Excel row and column start positions for writing Row=1 and Col=1
                        for (int col = 1; col <= table.Columns.Count; col++)
                        {
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = table.Rows[row][col - 1].ToString();
                        }
                        r++;
                    }
                }                  

                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int TotalStock = 0;
                    decimal TotalBQTYSFT = 0;
                    int TotalTodayMarked = 0;
                    decimal TotalMQTYSFT = 0;
                    int TotalMarked = 0;
                    decimal TotalTMQTYSFT = 0;
                    int TotalBalanceNos = 0;
                    decimal TotalGrandQTYSFT = 0;

                    TotalStock = Convert.ToInt32(table.Compute("SUM(Stock)", "Color = '" + dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BlockColor"].ToString() + "'"));
                    TotalBQTYSFT = Convert.ToDecimal(table.Compute("SUM(BQTYSFT)", "Color = '" + dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BlockColor"].ToString() + "'"));
                    TotalTodayMarked = Convert.ToInt32(table.Compute("SUM(TodayMarked)", "Color = '" + dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BlockColor"].ToString() + "'"));
                    TotalMQTYSFT = Convert.ToDecimal(table.Compute("SUM(MQTYSFT)", "Color = '" + dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BlockColor"].ToString() + "'"));
                    TotalMarked = Convert.ToInt32(table.Compute("SUM(TotalMarked)", "Color = '" + dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BlockColor"].ToString() + "'"));
                    TotalTMQTYSFT = Convert.ToDecimal(table.Compute("SUM(TMQTYSFT)", "Color = '" + dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BlockColor"].ToString() + "'"));
                    TotalBalanceNos = Convert.ToInt32(table.Compute("SUM(BalanceNos)", "Color = '" + dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BlockColor"].ToString() + "'"));
                    TotalGrandQTYSFT = Convert.ToDecimal(table.Compute("SUM(GrandQTYSFT)", "Color = '" + dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BlockColor"].ToString() + "'"));

                    for (int col = 1; col <= table.Columns.Count; col++)
                    {
                        ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = "";
                    }
                    r++;

                    for (int col = 1; col <= table.Columns.Count; col++)
                    {
                        if (table.Columns[col - 1].ColumnName == "Stock")
                        {
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = TotalStock.ToString();
                        }
                        if (table.Columns[col - 1].ColumnName == "BQTYSFT")
                        {
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = TotalBQTYSFT.ToString();
                        }
                        if (table.Columns[col - 1].ColumnName == "TodayMarked")
                        {
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = TotalTodayMarked.ToString();
                        }
                        if (table.Columns[col - 1].ColumnName == "MQTYSFT")
                        {
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = TotalMQTYSFT.ToString();
                        }
                        if (table.Columns[col - 1].ColumnName == "TotalMarked")
                        {
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = TotalMarked.ToString();
                        }
                        if (table.Columns[col - 1].ColumnName == "TMQTYSFT")
                        {
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = TotalTMQTYSFT.ToString();
                        }
                        if (table.Columns[col - 1].ColumnName == "BalanceNos")
                        {
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = TotalBalanceNos.ToString();
                        }
                        if (table.Columns[col - 1].ColumnName == "GrandQTYSFT")
                        {
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = TotalGrandQTYSFT.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    r++;
                }

                try
                {
                    ExcelWorkSheet.Name = dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Abbreviation"].ToString();//Renaming the ExcelSheets
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExcelWorkSheet.Name = dsColors.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Abbreviation"].ToString() + string.Format("{0:d}", Math.Abs(i - DateTime.Now.Millisecond));
                }

            }
            string filePath = "C:\\NetStockReport\\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            }
            string FileName = filePath+"NetStockReport" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")+".xlsx";
            ExcelWorkBook.SaveAs(FileName);               
            ExcelWorkBook.Close();
            ExcelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
        }
```

Thanks,
Purna.

Comment: I assume your code working on the web. You can generate the file in memory by use memory stream and put it into the response with header is application/vnd.ms-excel for MS Excel 2007 and application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet for MS Excel 2010 or above. The user will make decision they want to download and save to any location they want.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                // your code to write the file content
            }
            string fileName = "yourfilename.csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add below code on bottom of your code:

```
var excelFilePathMap = Server.MapPath(FileName);
return new FilePathResult(excelFilePathMap, "application/octet-stream");
```

i.e. after last line of your code: Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);

it will ask user to download the file.

Comment: Hi, I didn't find the method FilePathResult() , I need to add any dll or reference for that.  @raju1208

Comment: pls add using System.Web.Mvc;